# Can't add '0' as a shortcut to Qt app, others work

Tags: qt, user-interface, shortcut

I'm making a calculator and I wan't to make the 0-9 digits capable to be entered from the keyboard. So I've created QPushButton's connected them with my slot and to each button I added a shortcut (0-9). For all other buttons I allso added shortcuts and they all work. Only the '0' one doesn't. I've been adding them in the Qt Design so I just entered the desired shortcut into a window.

[image: Button0 property editor]

Buttons are named Button0,..., Button9 and are connected this way:

```js
ui->Display->setText(QString::number(calcVal, 'g', span));
    QPushButton *numButtons[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        QString butName = "Button" + QString::number(i);
        numButtons[i] = Calculator::findChild<QPushButton *>(butName);
        connect(numButtons[i], SIGNAL(released()), this,
                SLOT(NumPressed()));
    }//for
```

The function looks like that:

```js
void Calculator::NumPressed()
{
    if (nowy)
    {
        ui->Display->setText("");
        nowy = false;
    }//if
    if (mathBut)
    {
        ui->Display->setText("");
        mathBut = false;
    }//if
    QPushButton *button = (QPushButton *)sender();
    butVal = button->text();
    displayVal = ui->Display->text();
    QString zero = "0";
    if(displayVal == zero)
        ui->Display->setText(butVal);
    else
        ui->Display->setText(displayVal.append(butVal));

    rBracket = false;
}//void
```

But I don't think that that's the problem because if I click the button by mouse it works properly only the shortcut doesn't work while it's '0'. When I changed it to e.g. 'K' or 'J' it worked.

The shortcut is assigned in the xml file:

```js
<widget class="QPushButton" name="Button0">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>280</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: Silver;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>0</string>
    </property>
    <property name="shortcut">
     <string>0</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

(line 34-35)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, try creating a new blank project with just one button and set its shortcut to 0. If that will work (I tried and it worked fine for me in a new blank application), then there must be something in your calculator code which blocks this shortcut. Aren't you using 0 as shortcut in some other part of the application? There must be something wrong in other parts of your code which you have not shown, because the parts which you have shown look OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of: the `0` shortcut is already assigned to something else in that same widget. Maybe you could open the ui file in edit mode and find `<string>0</string>`, using Select All, then scroll the file top to bottom to find the 'shadowing' one.

A (maybe) quicker way: notice if Button0 at least takes focus when zero is pressed, then lose it when zero is pressed again. If yes: try to visually track the focus (i.e. see to what other control is being assigned).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I cloned that button and forgot to change the shortcut for the new ones and that blocked the action.